# Receiving SIGTERM from OS

Tags: linux, unix, process

Can OS (Linux) send SIGTERM to a process? If yes, when? In what situations?
For example, when my process write to incorrect address memory OS sends to it SIGSEGV.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

> Can OS (Linux) send SIGTERM to a process? If yes, when? In what situations?

When Linux shuts down or reboots it sends `SIGTERM` to each process.

When you invoke `kill <pid>` (without specifying the signal) it sends `SIGTERM` to the process.

[Magic SysRq key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key) can be used to send `SIGTERM`.

[Some drivers can send `SIGTERM`.](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/ident/SIGTERM)

Comment: ok. What about other situations  (excluding rebooting and shutdowning).

Comment: @Logic Other situations are: specifying wrong pid to `kill` command.

Comment: The OOM-killer sends `SIGTERM`.

Comment: @Barmar If it did, then you would be able to ignore it. OOM-killer sends `SIGKILL`.

Comment: You're probably right. [this page](http://www.linuxdevcenter.com/pub/a/linux/2006/11/30/linux-out-of-memory.html?page=2) says `SIGTERM`, but other resources I've found say `SIGKILL`. Is it possible it does both, sending `SIGTERM` first to allow the process to clean up, then `SIGKILL` to kill it if the signal is ignored?

Comment: @Barmar [OOM-killer sends `SIGKILL` only](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/mm/oom_kill.c#L882).